# Python Watermarking - Prevent image size and quality reduction

Tags: python, watermark

I have this script which is successfully applying a watermark to an image, resizing the watermark and setting the image "quality".
I find that it's actually reducing the quality and resizing it to be smaller than I want.

This is a telegram bot that I'm using, I send the image to the bot, the bot is adding the watermark and then resizing. I don't want the resizing part at all. I want the original size + the watermark.

**QUESTION**: How do i change this so it doesn't resize my original image that the watermark is added to?

**CURRENT FLOW**

1. I sent image to my bot which activates the script
2. The script adds a watermark and resizes the image
3. The script sends the resized image back to me with the watermark included

**DESIRED FLOW**

1. I send image to my bot which activates script
2. The script adds a watermark **but does not resize the original image**
3. The script sends the image back to me with the watermark included

**CODE 1**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import config
import random
import os
import time
from tools.tools import getting_ready

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi, Send or Forward me a PHOTO!')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Send /start or /help')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def send_watermark(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    sent_message = bot.reply_to(message, 'Downloading...')
    message_id = sent_message.message_id
    file = bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    bot.edit_message_text(f'Downloaded!\n\nNow, Genarating Watermarks...\n\ncurrent watermark: {config.WATERMARK}', chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)
    __path = 'images/' + str(random.randint(100000, 999999)) + '.tmp'
    with open(__path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(downloaded_file)
    fname = getting_ready(__path)
    os.remove(__path)
    time.sleep(2)
    bot.edit_message_text('Now, Uploading...', chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)
    for i in ('black','white',):
        __file = 'images/out/{}/{}'.format(i, fname)
        __photo = open(__file, 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, __photo, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
        os.remove(__file)
    bot.delete_message(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)


print('watermark bot started successfully!')
bot.polling()
```

**CODE 2**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance
import hashlib
import piexif
import config


def getting_ready(path):
    fname = md5(path) + '.jpg'
    image = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    try:
        exif_dict = piexif.load(image.info['exif'])
        orientation = exif_dict['0th'][274]
    except KeyError:
        orientation = None
    rotate_values = {3: 180, 6: 270, 8: 90}
    if orientation in rotate_values:
        image = image.rotate(rotate_values[orientation], expand=True)
    for color in ['black', 'white']:
        watermark(image, fname, color)
    return fname


def watermark(img, new_fname, color):
    text = config.WATERMARK
    wm = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    fontsize = img.size[1] // 100 * config.FONT_SIZE
    font = ImageFont.truetype(f'tools/fonts/{config.FONT_NAME}', fontsize)
    indent = fontsize // 8
    w, h = font.getsize(text)
    text_position = (img.size[0] - w - indent, img.size[1] - h - indent)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(wm, 'RGBA')
    draw.text(text_position, text, font=font, fill=color)
    alpha = wm.split()[3]
    alpha = ImageEnhance.Brightness(alpha).enhance(config.TRANSPARENCY)
    wm.putalpha(alpha)
    out_path = 'images/out/{}/{}'.format(color, new_fname)
    Image.composite(wm, img, wm).save(out_path, 'JPEG', optimize=False, quality=config.QUALITY)


def md5(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        md5hash = hashlib.md5()
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b''):
            md5hash.update(chunk)
    return md5hash.hexdigest()
```

Comment: what's the actual question?

Comment: Edited the post to have a clear question and expected flow

Comment: The code formatting is broken...

Comment: Besides, the code is a little too large for a [example], and also incomplete (it won't do anything by itself, and also requires a bunch of external image files)

Comment: added complete code

Comment: I suggest you to test your code without using telegram first.  I noticed that `PIL.Image.composite()` requires the 2 image with the same size and mode. Please check this.

Comment: The bot and script is working currently in telegram for me but it's shrinking the images. I have the code fully live on heroku running.

Comment: what yoonghm said. print out all the image sizes as you go.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to test it first @yoonghm. It's currently working via telegram. It's taking my uploaded image, applying a watermark, resizing and sending it back. I want to stop the resizing

Comment: @Imtryingbigtime, you can use call `PIL.Image.composite()` with the original and watermark images to ensure that the output image could maintain its image resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to fix this but it worked for me to bring it back to a normal size

```
double = 2.0
    Image.composite(wm, img, wm).resize( [int(double * s) for s in img.size] ).save(out_path, 'JPEG', optimize=True, quality=config.QUALITY)
```